# Library for working with Excel - jxl?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

How reliable and powerful is jxl? I'm trying to create an excel file from Java, performing operations like merging cells, creating graphs, setting different background colours (with gradients) - basing on information I collect from the user. Also, I would like to name sheets with current date and set access rights (read-only or editable). Can I do all this using jxl?

Comment: It is easy to use, but has limitations from the old file format supported.

Comment: WARNING: jxl call GC explicitly by default, which will cause your super-fast-highly-concurrent-performance-optimized web server to halt. save some white hair and use `-Djxl.nogc=true `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Merging Cells - Yes
- Creating Graphs - I don't believe so.
- Background colors - Yes
- Background colors with gradients - No
- Name Sheets - Yes
- Set access rights to sheets - Yes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding background colors with gradients, would it be possible to specify RGB values to obtain desired colors? And regarding naming sheets - what I'm looking for is to pass current date `Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();` as a name for the sheet `workbook.createSheet("the date", 0);` if that would still be possible

Comment: Here's a perfect way to set the date as the name of the sheet: DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"); String theDate = df.format(now); workbook.createSheet(theDate, 0); Regarding the background colors: I really don't think so, but I honestly am not 100% certain, purely because I've never spent a significant amount of effort to try. But my strong inclination is that it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, when I try it, I get error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleDateFormat to DateFormat`

Comment: Instead of importing java.sql.Date, import java.util.Date

Comment: I imported java.util.Date `Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
   String theDate = df.format(now); 
   workbook.createSheet(theDate, 0);`